# Why does btreemap's iter not implement count?

Tags: rust, iterator, b-tree

I wonder about the [`Iterator for Iter` implementation of `BTreeMaps` `Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/btree/map.rs.html#1490-1524):

> ```
> #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
> impl<'a, K: 'a, V: 'a> Iterator for Iter<'a, K, V> {
>     type Item = (&'a K, &'a V);
>
>     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(&'a K, &'a V)> {
>         if self.length == 0 {
>             None
>         } else {
>             self.length -= 1;
>             Some(unsafe { self.range.next_unchecked() })
>         }
>     }
>
>     fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
>         (self.length, Some(self.length))
>     }
>
>     fn last(mut self) -> Option<(&'a K, &'a V)> {
>         self.next_back()
>     }
>
>     fn min(mut self) -> Option<(&'a K, &'a V)>
>     where
>         (&'a K, &'a V): Ord,
>     {
>         self.next()
>     }
>
>     fn max(mut self) -> Option<(&'a K, &'a V)>
>     where
>         (&'a K, &'a V): Ord,
>     {
>         self.next_back()
>     }
> }
> ```

Only some functions are implemented, and `count` should be very easy to implement. Just return `len`. Why use `next`?

I'd love to know some details about iterator design, maybe I've been missing something key this whole time.

Comment: You can open a PR.

Comment: BTreeMap implements the ExactSizeIterator, whereas count is documented as traversing the iterator, so it would be surprising for count to delegate to len.

Comment: @user1937198 as a counter example, slice `.iter()` implements `count()` to be its `len()`

Comment: @user1937198 You're correct, any random iterator might have side-effects. However some iterators such as for slice, maps, sets, etc. do not have any side-effects. So they usually specialize the implementation to simply return the remaining count.